# I am attempting to make a bot that tweets the bee movie script one line at a time, but am getting errors. Any help is much appreciated

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am a beginner coder and an doing a project where I make a twitter bot that tweets the bee movie script one line at a time. However, whenever I try this code, I get no errors, but nothing happens. Any help matters a lot. The txt file is a copy of the script with spaces in between lines.

```
tweet = True
while(tweet == True):
    f = open('script.txt', 'r')
    for word in f:
        if word == '\n':
            continue
        text = f.readline()
        api.update_status(text)
        time.sleep(120)
```

I tried changing the code around, but nothing has helped.

Comment: what does script.txt look like?

Comment: Can you update your question to make your title and description consistent? (eg. Which film script do you want to tweet a line at a time?)

Comment: the problem is probably the api.update_status(text). When i switch out that with 'print(text)' and my script.txt has one word per line, the code works.

Comment: So, are you getting any errors or not? And what is `api`?

Comment: As a side note, don't ever compare things `== True` or `== False`.  Just write `while tweet:`.  Also, we don't use parentheses in `while` statements.  That's a leftover from C.  Also, the code you have is going to skip every other line.  You don't need `text = f.readline()`, because you already have the next line in `word`.